# running ansible-playbook from java

Tags: java, ansible

I have been trying to run anisble-playbooks using Java (runtime().exec() and ProcessBuilder), and in both instances I see that the extra variables that I wish to pass using the commandline never get executed or so it seems.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("ansible-playbook", "/root/playbooks/script-ilo.yml", "-e", "'@/tmp/vars.yml'");
```

and

```
String[] ansible_run = {"ansible-playbook", "/root/playbooks/script-ilo.yml", "-e", "'@/tmp/vars.yml'"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ansible_run,null);
```

I packed the code as a jar and executed in test system and in both cases, ansible runs the playbook and throws an error.

```
# java -jar /home/admin/test-script.jar

PLAY [esxi] ********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [192.168.50.100]

TASK [Set XML with new secrets] ************************************************
fatal: [192.168.50.100]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'change_user' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/playbooks/script-ilo.yml': line 3, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Set XML with new secrets\n      ^ here\n"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/root/playbooks/script-ilo.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.50.100             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

When I run the command `ansible-playbook /root/playbooks/script-ilo.yml -e '@/tmp/vars.yml'`
in the shell, it run perfect.

I need help with getting unblocked here. If there is a better way to do this, I am all ears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `String[] ansible_run = {"ansible-playbook", "/root/playbooks/script-ilo.yml", "-e", "'@/tmp/vars.yml'"};`

Don't put single quotes in that `-e` value; the single quotes are only needed for your shell, but `ProcessBuilder` doesn't go through your shell, so the arguments don't need to be escaped.

I was actually expecting ansible to whine when I fed it a blatantly bogus `-e`, but it turns out that any such value is passed in to the `hostvars` as `_raw_params`, so in your case, it would have set a value like:

```
"hostvars": {
    "192.168.50.100": {
        "_raw_params": "'@/tmp/vars.yml'",
```

Comment: that was it! stupid `' '` messed up my whole evening.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced a similar issue and solved it using the following

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("ansible-playbook", "/etc/ansible/playbooks_vmware/diskadd1.yaml","-e","vm_name=web04 addSizeInGB=40 scsi=0 unit_number=1");
```